# How to bash sort txt file with whitespace and ':' colon

Tags: bash, sorting

For example, here is the file I want to sort.

```
A:2   B:9
A:9   B:12
A:32  B:23
A:2   B:3
A:21  B:33
```

how can I output the line where the value after 'B:' is the largest?

```
A:21  B:33
```

Answer (score 4):

Using awk you can do this in a single command without any need of sorting which can be very expensive for a large file:

```
awk -F'[: ]+' '$4>max{max=$4; line=$0} END{print line}' file

A:21  B:33
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat /tmp/a
A:2   B:9
A:9   B:12
A:32  B:23
A:2   B:3
A:21  B:33

$ sort -t: -k3rn /tmp/a | head -1
A:21  B:33
```

Comment: Even if you get the correct answer, this is not sorting by the number after `B:`

Comment: @DawidGrabowski Yes, but I am leveraging the fact that `B:` is common in all elements of the second column.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Look at what you get without the pipe to head.

Comment: @DawidGrabowski How about now?

Comment: Yes, this one is correct. I also posted a version using keys.

Answer (score 2):

Other option with **sed**:

```
sort -k1.9,1.10 -rn file | head -1
```

Sorting by 9th and 10th character (after `B:`)